# Как исправить ошибку 'name "message" is not defined'? Pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telebot

Как убрать ошибку `name "message" is not defined.`? Я понимаю, что проблема в том, что я не могу зарегистрировать введенный текст пользователем и перейти в другую функцию, но мне это нужно обязательно. Как можно это исправить? Вот кусочек кода, где ошибка:

```
def knopki2(message):            
     knop2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
     but1_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('2', callback_data = 'two')
     but2_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('3', callback_data='three')
     but2_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('4', callback_data='four')
     knop2.add(but1_2, but2_2, but2_3)
     input2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Выбери кол-во декора и я подсчитаю материалы ", reply_markup=knop2) 
     bot.register_next_step_handler(input2, lol2)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)                   
def lol2(call):
      if call.message:                                 
          if(call.data == "two"):
               podg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи первое название мебели")
               bot.register_next_step_handler(podg, pod01)
```

Comment: Хендлер(декоратор) покажите хоть

Comment: Походу, при добавлении вопроса он исчез. Добавил

Comment: Покажите как выглядит кнопка (картинка), а также код этой кнопки

Comment: Исправил, но, я так понял, под картинкой кнопки Вы подразумеваете скриншот?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD2. Вы неправильно использовали register_next_step_handler

```
def knopki2(message: types.Message):
    knop2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    but1_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('2', callback_data='two')
    but2_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('3', callback_data='three')
    but2_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('4', callback_data='four')
    knop2.add(but1_2, but2_2, but2_3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     text="Выбери кол-во декора и я подсчитаю материалы ",
                     reply_markup=knop2)
    # вообще не нужен
    # bot.register_next_step_handler(message, lol2)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def lol2(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    # бесполезное условие
    # if call.message:
    # не пихайте условие в скобки просто так 
    # if (call.data == "two"):
    if call.data == "two":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Введи первое название мебели")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, pod01)
```

Comment: Ошибка: `name "message" is not defined` в строчке `podg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи первое название мебели")` внутри функции lol2

Comment: @СёгунРайдэн обновил

Comment: Попробовал, выводит ту же ошибку. Изменял в строчке `podg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи первое название мебели")` на `podg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Введи первое название мебели")`. Тогда выводит ошибку `'Message' object has no attribute 'message'` в  `if call.message:`

Comment: @СёгунРайдэн очень странно, а сделайте принт call

Comment: В консоль выводит без проблем, но вот при добавлении переменной podg и register_next_step_handler, указывает на ошибку в `if call.message`

Comment: @СёгунРайдэн это круто что он выводит, я хочу чтобы вы сюда отправили результат принта. Да и вообще зачем эта проверка call.message если она все равно вызывает ошибку?

Comment: @СёгунРайдэн обновил ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо! Учту ошибки у себя. Всё заработало

Answer (score 0):

```
def lol2(call):
      if call.message:                                 
          if call.data == "two":
               podg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи первое название мебели")
               bot.register_next_step_handler(podg, pod01)
              
          elif call.message.text == "/menu":
              menu(call.message)
          
          elif call.message.text == "/start":
              start(call.message)
```

Я думаю что это не очень удачная идея, обрабатывать все сообщения в одной функции. Почитайте про message_handler

Comment: Учту Ваш комментарий и почитаю!